# Slider filtering edges by property (e.g., strength [0-1])

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am a newbie in Cytoscape js, is there an example of how to filter down all edges that has an attribute lower than a certain threshold (using a slider)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code bellow shows how to filter edges by an attribute, in this example `weight` using a variable named `threshold`. The `elements` variable will have the filtered edges.

```js
var elements = cy.filter('edges[weight > ' + threshold + ']')
```

The slider callback method could be used to trigger this function, resulting in a filter controlled by a slider.

If you wish to remove those elements from the graph, the [restore function](http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.restore) could be useful to return them back before filtering the graph again. An snippet of a possible callback method is given bellow:

```js
var filteredEdges =  [];
sliderCalback(threshold) {
   // putting back the previously removed edges
   cy.recover(filteredEdges);
   // filtering edges
   filteredEdges = cy.filter('edges[weight> ' + threshold + ']');
   // Removing filteredEdges from graph
   cy.remove(filteredEdges);
}
```

More details on Cytoscape.js filter method can be found [here](http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.filter), and selectors can be found [here](http://js.cytoscape.org/#selectors/data).